# login por medio de txt

Tags: java, java-ee

Debo realizar un proyecto `Java` basado en `EJB`, el cual simule el proceso de un banco sencillo (cuenta, clave y saldo). Se usa un archivo `txt` como `DB`.

Debo hacer la validación de la cuenta y clave y, si es correcta, mostrar el saldo correspondiente. Todo es por consola, así que se usará la librería `Scanner` para ingresar los datos de cuenta y clave. El archivo se llama `base.txt`.

```
CUENTA | CLAVE | SALDO
```

[image]

Ese es la clase del `SessionBean`

```
public void login() {
    String record = null;
    FileReader in = null;

    try {
        in = new FileReader("db.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Cuenta: ");
        String cuenta = scn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Password: ");
        String pass = scn.nextLine();

        while ((record = br.readLine()) !=null) {
            if (cuenta.equals(record) && pass.equals(record)) {
                System.out.println("Ingreso correcto mostrar saldo");
            } else {
                System.out.println("________----Error----________\n press 'Enter' to continue...");
                scn.nextLine();

            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getCause();
    }
}
```

Ésta es la clase `Main` donde llamo al método:

```
@EJB
private static MySessionRemote mySession;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    mySession.login();

    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

Llamo al método, pero este no se ejecuta correctamente.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que has intentado hasta ahora? De momento, solo veo el enunciado del ejercicio.

Comment: si ya edite, se me paso adjuntar codigo

Comment: Indicas que no se ejecuta el método correctamente, ¿qué problema/error recibes?

Comment: run-deploy:
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\david\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EJBCliente\dist
Copying 2 files to C:\Users\david\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EJBCliente\dist\EJBClienteClient
Warning: C:\Users\david\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EJBCliente\dist\gfdeploy\EJBCliente does not exist.
run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 23 seconds)

Comment: El problema está en cómo haces la comprobación dentro del bucle `while`, si no me equivoco.

Answer (score 1):

Es lógico que no funcione. Si te fijas en el código, lo primero que haces es leer el fichero `db.txt` línea a línea:

```
while ((record = br.readLine()) !=null) {
```

Una vez dentro, una sentencia `if` comprueba si todo el valor de la variable `record`, que en este caso es la línea completa del fichero `db.txt`, es igual a `cuenta` y `pass`, lo cual es imposible.

Si introduces valores correctos para `cuenta` y `pass` como los del siguiente ejemplo, en la primera vuelta del bucle `while` estás haciendo lo siguiente:

```
Valor introducido variable cuenta = 101522
Valor introducido variable pass = 2B6E
Valor variable record en la primera vuelta = 101522 2B6E 520000
```

Toda comparación de `cuenta` y `pass` con `record` devolverá falso.

Ya que el formato del fichero `db.txt` es `texto texto texto`, la solución sería almacenar en un `array` las 3 palabras de la línea recogida en cada vuelta del bucle `while`, utilizando `split` con el delimitador `" "`.

El código sería algo similar a esto:

```
public static void login() {
    String record = null;
    FileReader in = null;
    boolean existe = false; // para comprobar si cuenta y pass no coindicen con ninguna línea 

    try {
        in = new FileReader("db.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Cuenta: ");
        String cuenta = scn.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Password: ");
        String pass = scn.nextLine();

        while ((record = br.readLine()) !=null) {
            String [] word = record.split(" "); // dividir en palabras delimitadas por espacios
            if (word[0].equals(cuenta) && word[1].equals(pass)) {
                System.out.println("Saldo de la cuenta " + cuenta + ": " + word[2]);
                existe = true;
            }
        }

        if (!existe) {
            System.out.println("Usuario o contraseña incorrecto.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.getCause();
    }
}
```

Lo que hacemos dividiendo la línea recogida y almacenándola en un `array` es lo siguiente:

```
word[0] = primera posición de la línea, es decir, la cuenta
word[1] = segunda posición de la línea, es decir, la contraseña
word[2] = tercera posición de la línea, es decir, el saldo de la cuenta
```

La salida del programa ahora será:

```
run:
Cuenta: 102111
Password: A536
Saldo de la cuenta 102111: 5000
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 6 seconds)
```

Comment: Perfecto, gracias por ayudarme, lo implementare al rato y te cuento, porque como tal el servidor proporciona el metodo, pero el cliente debe ingresar los datos y con los datos del cliente el servidor los valida y los ejecuta si son correctos.

Comment: Creo que funcionará, ya que el objetivo es el mismo. Intenta realizar tests y no dudes en escribir en los comentarios si surge algún problema para poder ver qué ocurre.

Comment: Hola, mira ya lo probe directamente en un main pero no me inicia, al ejecutar aparece:run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Comment: @DavidAlejandroLarrota si has copiado el código entero, date cuenta de que es una función, debe llamarse desde `main`. Lo correcto sería copiarlo en la clase `SessionBean` y realizar la llamada desde la clase `main` tal y como lo tienes en la pregunta.

Comment: Si quieres copiarlo en la clase `main` y no utilizar el método login, no debes copiar la declaración del método como tal, solo el contenido

Comment: Si entiendo, eso lo realice, acabo de dar una respuesta mas detallada con el error al ejecutar.

Answer (score 0):

Session Bean:

```
@Stateless

public class ejecutarBanco implements ejecutarBancoRemote {
    @Override
    public void cargar(String a, String b) {
    String record;
    FileReader in;
    boolean existe = false; // para comprobar si cuenta y pass no coindicen con ninguna línea 

        try {
            in = new FileReader("src/bd.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);


            while ((record = br.readLine()) !=null) {
                String [] word = record.split(" "); // dividir en palabras delimitadas por espacios
                if (word[0].equals(a) && word[1].equals(b)) {
                    System.out.println("Saldo de la cuenta " + ": " + word[2]);
                    existe = true;
                }
            }

            if (!existe) {
                System.out.println("Usuario o contraseña incorrecto.");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getCause();
        }

    }
}
```

Main InterfazCliente:

```
@EJB
private static ejecutarBancoRemote ejecutarBanco;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
   Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Ingrese cuenta:");
    String cuenta = scn.next();

    System.out.println("Ingrese clave:");
    String clave = scn.next();

    ejecutarBanco.cargar(cuenta, clave);
}
```

Al ejecutar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]